# Flask application doesn't take into account the arguments in app.run()?

Tags: python, flask, web

I have this issue : I use arguments to set the port and the debugger on like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=4200, debug=True)
```

but it isn't taken into account when I click on the run button (I use Pycharm pro and the project I create is a Flask Project)

The terminal shows this :

```
FLASK_APP = app.py
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 0
In folder $FOLDERPATH
$PATH\python.exe -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `app.run` is only relevant when `__name__` == `__main__`...that is, when your code is the main entrypoint. But as you can see from the terminal output, Pycharm isn't calling `python app.py`, it is in fact calling:

```
python -m flask run
```

In this case, the `flask` module is the main entrypoint, and you would control things like the port or debug mode through environment variables (like `FLASK_DEBUG`) or command line parameters (`python -m flask run --port 4200`).

According to [the pycharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-flask-server.html#1), you can see command line parameters for the `flask run` command using the "Additional options" field.